# Empty message from facebook messenger bot

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I followed the guide to build a facebook messenger bot from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start)

but in my software I receive alway an empty response.

here my bot code:

```
    define('PAGE_TOKEN',"xxx");
    define('VERIFY_TOKEN',"xxx");

    if(isset($_GET['hub_mode']) && isset($_GET['hub_challenge']) && isset($_GET['hub_verify_token'])) {
        if($_GET['hub_verify_token']==VERIFY_TOKEN && $_GET['hub_mode']=='subscribe') {
            echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
        }
    }

    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    // Get the Senders Graph ID
    $sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
    // Get the returned message
    $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

    error_log($input);
    error_log($sender);
    error_log($message);
```

the verify phase is fine, but when i send a messagge to my bot in my error_log file I found only empty values:

```
    [Sun Aug 13 17:35:49.617919 2017] [:error] [pid 22501] [client 173.252.124.11:18834]
    [Sun Aug 13 17:35:49.617951 2017] [:error] [pid 22501] [client 173.252.124.11:18834]
    [Sun Aug 13 17:35:49.617972 2017] [:error] [pid 22501] [client 173.252.124.11:18834]
```

Here there is also my access_log:

```
    173.252.124.30 - - [13/Aug/2017:17:35:48 +0200] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 301 3621 "-" "-"
    173.252.124.11 - - [13/Aug/2017:17:35:49 +0200] "GET /webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 200 328 "-" "-"
```

so why the **$input** variable is alway empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
173.252.124.30 - - [13/Aug/2017:17:35:48 +0200] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 301 3621 "-" "-"
173.252.124.11 - - [13/Aug/2017:17:35:49 +0200] "GET /webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 200 328 "-" "-"
```

Your server answers the POST request with a 301 redirect, so that the client (Facebook) has to make a GET request next, and therefor you see no more POST data.

Seeing that the first  URL is `/webhook`, and gets redirected to `/webhook/`, this is likely just an automatic trailing slash redirect, and should be fixed once you specify the correct URL with the trailing slash in your app settings to begin with.

Comment: thanks you! you save my day!
I modified the webhook in `https://mydomain/webhook/index.php` and now i can read the messages